# How can I add a vertical line to a plotly chart in R with the y variable a factor

Tags: r, plotly

I have a data.frame where I  plot a value,id, on the y axis against a value t on the x axis ordered by another value s

```
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)

# create data.frame
df <- data.frame(id=c("a","b","c"),s=c(1,3,2),t=c(3,2,1))

# set order
levels <- df %>% 
arrange(s) %>% 
.$id #[1] a c b

# plot
df %>% 
mutate(id=factor(id, levels = levels)) %>%
plot_ly(x=~t,y=~id) %>% 
add_markers()
```

This works fine.

[image]

However I want to add a vertical line indicating the average of t, weighted by s

```
line <- weighted.mean(df$t,df$s)
```

and I am unable to find the correct way to do it

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to prevent Plotly to sort the y-axis with the categorical values you could draw multiple lines which appear as one.

```
p <- add_lines(p, 
               x = rep(line, nrow(df)), 
               y = df$id)
```

[image]

---

```
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)

# create data.frame
df <- data.frame(id=c("a","b","c"),s=c(1,3,2),t=c(3,2,1))

# set order
levels <- df %>% 
  arrange(s) %>% 
  .$id #[1] a c b

# plot
p <- df %>% 
  mutate(id=factor(id, levels = levels)) %>%
  plot_ly(x=~t,y=~id) %>% 
  add_markers()

line <- weighted.mean(df$t,df$s)


p <- add_lines(p, 
               x = rep(line, nrow(df)), 
               y = df$id)
p
```

Comment: I want a vertical line at the weighted average point (so in this example it would be at 1.83) extending all the way from 'a' to 'b' in my plot.  x_values = weighted.mean(df$t,df$s) places the line in correct place but something like y_values=c(as.character(levels[1]), as.character(levels[length(levels)])) does put the line between a and b as desired but reorders the y axis to be alphabetical which is not what I want

Comment: @pssguy: Thanks for the clarification! See updated answer.

Comment: @Maximillian Peters  Thanks so much. In the corrected code, I think we can now do without the x_values & y_values. More importantly, I believe it should be nrow(df) not length(df). I think the latter only works in this example as the number of rows equals the number of columns. If you can just confirm I am correct here then I will tick this as answer

Comment: @MP I have edited the final solution as well. In for peer review. Have not done before so hopefully correctly

Comment: @pssguy: lgtm :)